# InputAccessoryView hide after keyboard dismiss

Tags: react-native

`InputAccessoryView` hide after keyboard dismiss. I want to show always it at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using this npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-accessory